# Синтаксическая ошибка в подготовке динамического запроса openrowset

Tags: sql, sql-server, xls

Всем привет, помогите найти ошибку.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000) = '
    INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(
       ''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', 
       ''Excel 12.0;Database=D:\file.xlsx;HDR=YES'',
       ''select DATE, CODE, LABEL, CNT, CU, SCO, DISCOUNT FROM [Sheet1$]'')'
    exec sp_executesql @sql
    Select ..
```

Ошибка такая:
**Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции ")".**

Comment: Ну вообще-то INSERT INTO предполагает наличие не только сведений, куда вставлять, но и сведений, что вставлять...

Comment: Select .. - это полноценный запрос, просто не стал его целиком писать.

Comment: *Select .. - это полноценный запрос* А вот UPDATE в параметрах OPENROWSET() - кастрированный...

Comment: эммм..и как это может помочь ?))

Comment: @noanother это поможет исправить ошибку, я дал вам ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0;Database=D:\file.xlsx;HDR=YES'',''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'') SELECT ...'
```

Ваш "полноценный запрос" должен быть частью динамического запроса.

Comment: Спасибо, но в целом проблема не решена...